# Over time of period got 400 bad request for restTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

Over time of period got 400 bad request for restTemplate
That means when deploy war on tomcat it working fine, but after some hours restTemplate throws Exception.

So, when we start tomcat server again, it start working fine for few hours.

My restTemplate configuration in applicationContext.xml is

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json">
                </property>
           </bean>
        </list>
     </property>
</bean>
```

and on my service autowired like

```
    @Autowired
        private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    and service code like

        HttpEntity<Queue> queueMap = new HttpEntity<Queue>(queueItem);
        try {
        queueList = restTemplate.postForObject(HMS_QUEUE_URL + "/fetchqueuebyrange", queueMap, QueueList.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            log.debug("PatQueueService-fetchApptQueueItemByApptDate :: " + pw.toString());
        }
```

Here I call mongo restService via restTemplate.

Exception is

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad
>   Request at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:90)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:494)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:451)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:409)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:287)
>   at
>   com.genex.hms.patqueue.service.PatQueueServiceImpl.fetchQueueByRange(PatQueueServiceImpl.java:954)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor472.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.fetchQueueByRange(Unknown Source) at
>   com.genex.hms.patqueue.controller.QueueController.fetchAppointmentQueue(QueueController.java:282)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor471.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, resttemplate was working fine for initial number of requests. After a period of time (a number of requests sent), a 400 occured. The reason was that I was using a context managed restTemplate, like you managed by xml, but before each request I was adding a
    `restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add( new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());`

This lead to growing content of Accept header. Perhaps you are adding some behaviour to your restTemplate each time.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like a problem in code since its working for initial calls.

Can you add debug to record elements(name and values) placed in queueMap. and note the record for which it gives you the error.

Fire this record manually using a utility like chrome rest plugin, etc. and see the output.

It might probably be the mongo restService issue (Possibly) not accepting the data posted and throwing the error which your spring application catches.

This is just a test case to identify.